# error when trying to submit App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am done with my app so i wanted to put it in the app store. I got much errors but with this site i fixed them all. now i get a weird one.. hopefully someone knows what that means:

[image]

Comment: that doesn't really tell me anything, but i'm going to go out on a limb ands say its a code signing/provisioning problem for your distribution build.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like something is wrong with your provisioning profile.  Are you using a provisioning profile for use with the appstore or for development/ad-hoc?  Check your build settings for your target and ensure that the Code Signing section has your appstore provisioning profile set for "Release".

Good luck